# How can I show only specific users by their fields

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a class app and I want to show users if they are from the same class and section based on their fields and values on the Firestore database every student have a field of grade and section and they have values of the students under it. So basically the question is how can I show users from a specific class and section and this is how I am getting the students list.

```
fetchStudents() async {
    try {
      QuerySnapshot snapshot = await database
          .collection("users")
          .doc("UGCS")
          .collection("students")
          .orderBy("id", descending: false)
          .get();
      setState(() {
        students = snapshot.docs;
        isLoading = false;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

From this sentence in your question "based on their fields and values on the Firestore database every student have a field of grade and section" it seems that you should [filter the documents](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#filtering) within the desired `students` collection, by using the [`where()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/where.html) method.

This method can be chained onto a collection reference, as shown below:

```
  QuerySnapshot snapshot = await database
      .collection("users")
      .doc("UGCS")
      .collection("students")
      .where("grade", isEqualTo: "gradeB")   // For example gradeB
      .where("section", isEqualTo: "sectionA")  // For example sectionA
      .orderBy("id", descending: false)
      .get();
```

---

Note that you need to declare an [index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) for such a Query. Since you use `try/catch`, the first time you'll execute the query, the error message will contain a link that you can open in a browser and that will trigger, on the Firebase console, the index generation.

---

Finally, note the possibility to execute [`collectionGroup`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FirebaseFirestore/collectionGroup.html) queries, as explained in the Firestore [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).